# Is it possible to relocate a building expansion after it has been placed?

Tags: simcity-2013

One of the new features to the game is that you can expand certain buildings adding to its value.  You can add more classrooms to a school, add additional generators to a power plant, etc.

I'm working on a coal mining specialty and didn't notice that coal shafts can be chained off each other.  Well, I accidentally chained a shaft in a spot where I didn't want it and it removed a large building that was previously there.

[image: coal shaft expansion]

Coal mining is going well but it is a waste of space how it is currently laid out.  I was intending to place any large expansions behind the plant.  I wasn't planning to grow out further in the direction it is in right now.  Simply turning off the expansion does nothing and attempting to buldoze it selects the whole plant.

It seems like the only option for me is to demolish the entire building and rebuild placing the expansions again.  But that's easily over §50k that I don't want to have to spend again.

Is there a way to remove an expansion after it has been placed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out you can.  When in the edit view for the building, you may select the bulldozer to demolish a specific expansion.  Not in the normal city view, otherwise you'll bulldoze the entire building!

I was able to move the coal shafts to better locations.

[image: new and improved]

Comment: For me the demolish button is unclickable when in the edit view for the building. Any thoughts?

Comment: @House: try the hotkey instead, B. If that doesn't work, try restarting the game. It _should_ work as long as the game is cooperating.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks, think the game just wanted to make my life difficult.